How to formalize game theory in first order logic
In the answer to this question about Zermelo's theorem, Professor Hamkins states that the assertion "B has a winning strategy" can be expressed using the formula
$$\forall x_1\exists x_2\dots \vec x\text{ is a win for II}.$$
However, it is not clear to me what language (relation, function, and constant symbols) that statement requires or the explicit way to write $\vec x\text{ is a win for II}$.
I've tried to look for references that address the topic, but I haven't been able to find anything on this. And I could try to solve it on my own, but I can only think of how to do it for particular cases.

To start off with, there is a precise definition of the kind of "game" considered in set theory here. There you will also find a precise definition of what it means for a player to have a winning strategy. (I can't comment on how we should formalise the infinitary formula you wrote in your question, so I'll leave that for someone else.)

Thank you @Joe. However, is it really an infinitary formula? Since we are talking about finite games, I believed that $\vec{x}$ would be a finite tuple of variables.

@Petersu: yes, but the length of that tuple depends on the game and is unbounded. So there isn't a fixed statement of fixed quantifier depth that suffices for all games (at least not of this form).

Oh, thank you @QiaochuYuan. Silly mistake.

Bringing first-order logic into this is arguably a distraction. Finite games only have finitely many possible moves and game states so those quantifiers only range over finite sets, meaning they are just shorthand for a bunch of ANDs and ORs. So for any fixed finite game, or even for games of size bounded by a fixed positive integer $N$, the argument can be formalized in propositional logic, by a statement which gets larger as the games get larger.
If we want to write things down uniformly over all finite games, we need some kind of first-order theory whose models include such games. Then we run into the issue that Hamkins' argument requires considering a statement of unbounded quantifier depth, so it's not at all clear that first-order logic allows us to write down a single such statement which has the intended interpretation for arbitrarily large finite games.
One way or another we have to define "has a winning strategy" inductively. Here's a nice way to do this using the formalization of games considered in combinatorial game theory. The idea is that instead of formalizing games directly we formalize game states, and then "games" are just the special case where we consider the initial game state. The reason we want to do this is that game states have a recursive structure: at any given state of a game, each player has some possible moves they can make, and whatever a "move" is, it is something that changes the game state; afterwards the game is in some other state. A player wins if they can force the game into a state which prevents the other player from moving.
This leads to the following definition. Say we consider two players $L$ and $R$ (for "left" and "right") playing a game of perfect information. A finite game (or, more precisely, a game state) is defined recursively as follows:

The empty or zero game $0 = \{ \mid \}$ is the game in which neither player can move. Whoever moves loses.
If $L_1, \dots L_n$ and $R_1, \dots R_m$ are two finite sequences of games, then so is $\{ L_1, \dots L_n \mid R_1, \dots R_m \}$, the game where $L$'s possible moves are $L_i$ and where $R$'s possible moves are $R_j$. (Remember that by "move" here we are referring to the act of changing the entire game state to $L_i$ or $R_j$ respectively.)

This definition makes finite games into a structure similar to a hereditarily finite set, except that there are two notions of membership instead of one. We could formalize this using a first-order theory whose models are supposed to be collections of states of a game, equipped with two binary relations $\in_L, \in_R$, where $x \in_L y$ if $x$ is a possible move for $L$ in game state $y$, and $x \in_R y$ similarly for $R$.
"$L$ has a winning strategy" and "$R$ has a winning strategy" can now be defined by simultaneous structural induction. Actually we need to distinguish four statements: $L$ has a winning strategy if they move first resp. second, and the same for $R$. Write these as $L^1, L^2, R^1, R^2$ (my apologies for the partial notational clash here but I can't think of anything better). Then:

The zero game is a losing game state for both players, so $L^1(0) = R^1(0) = \bot$ (both players lose if moving first) and $L^2(0) = R^2(0) = \top$ (both players win if moving second).
If $G = \{ L_1, \dots L_n \mid R_1, \dots R_m \}$ is a game, then

$L^1(G) = \top$ iff there exists some $i$ such that $L^2(L_i) = \top$ (that is, $L$ wins moving first iff $L$ can force the game into a position from which $L$ wins moving second),
$R^1(G) = \top$ iff there exists some $j$ such that $R^2(R_j) = \top$,
$L^2(G) = \top$ iff for all $j$ we have $L^1(R_j) = \top$ (that is, $L$ wins moving second iff every move that $R$ can make leads to a win for $L$ moving first),
$R^2(G) = \top$ iff for all $i$ we have $R^1(L_i) = \top$.



Then in this language Zermelo's theorem says:

Theorem: If $G$ is a finite game then exactly one of $L^1(G)$ and $R^2(G)$ holds (if $L$ moves first, either $L$ wins or $R$ wins). Dually, exactly one of $L^2(G)$ and $R^1(G)$ holds (if $R$ moves first, either $L$ wins or $R$ wins).

Sketch. Just prove by structural induction that $\neg L^1(G) = R^2(G)$ and $\neg L^2(G) = R^1(G)$, which follows from observing that it holds in the base case and then applying de Morgan's laws to the inductive step of the definitions. $\Box$
So structural induction is what allows us to make precise this idea of writing down a statement of unbounded quantifier depth; each step of the induction adds a quantifier. I guess completely formalizing this in first-order logic would require writing down a structural induction axiom analogous to the first-order induction axiom for Peano arithmetic.

Thank you very much. Very interesting answer. Just to clarify things, that sentence constructed by structural induction is a $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$-sentence, right?

@Petersu: I guess so but I'm not familiar with infinitary logic at all. I would prefer to think about it as a recursively defined function.
